# NuGet upgrade issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, nuget

I have the version of NuGet that comes with MVC3 (1.0), but when I try to upgrade to the latest version (currently 1.4) it failes and I get this in the log file:

> 6/27/2011 1:25:08 PM - VSIXInstaller.SignatureMismatchException: The installed version of 'NuGet Package Manager' is signed, but the update version has an invalid signature. Therefore, Extension Manager cannot install the update.
>      at VSIXInstaller.Common.VerifyMatchingExtensionSignatures(IInstalledExtension installedExtension, IInstallableExtension updateExtension)
>      at VSIXInstaller.InstallProgressPage.BeginInstallVSIX(SupportedVSSKU targetAppID)
>
> 6/27/2011 1:25:08 PM - Install Error : VSIXInstaller.SignatureMismatchException: The installed version of 'NuGet Package Manager' is signed, but the update version has an invalid signature. Therefore, Extension Manager cannot install the update.
>      at VSIXInstaller.Common.VerifyMatchingExtensionSignatures(IInstalledExtension installedExtension, IInstallableExtension updateExtension)
>      at VSIXInstaller.InstallProgressPage.BeginInstallVSIX(SupportedVSSKU targetAppID)
>
> 6/27/2011 1:26:27 PM - VSIXInstaller.SignatureMismatchException: The installed version of 'NuGet Package Manager' is signed, but the update version has an invalid signature. Therefore, Extension Manager cannot install the update.
>      at VSIXInstaller.Common.VerifyMatchingExtensionSignatures(IInstalledExtension installedExtension, IInstallableExtension updateExtension)
>      at VSIXInstaller.InstallProgressPage.BeginInstallVSIX(SupportedVSSKU targetAppID)

I even tried uninstalling NuGet (via Add or Remove Programs) and installing 1.4 manually, but I inexplicably get the same message. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There's something deeply ironic about a program that is designed to update packages not being able to update itself, and not just once, but for years and years.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is documented on our Known Issues page: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/known-issues

There's two reasons why you might run into this issue. You've installed an unsigned or wrongly signed version of NuGet. For example, if you grab a build off of our continuous integration server (http://ci.nuget.org/) or if you installed one of our previous CodePlex releases.

There's another issue affecting some users of Windows XP or Windows 2003 where it appears the certificate authority on the machines are incorrectly reporting the certificate as not valid. We're still investigating this issue.

Comment: Any update regarding this issue on Windows XP? The update always fails, I have to uninstall and reinstall Nuget every time... On my Windows 7 machine it works fine.

Comment: Why not just add a confirmation dialog like a browser where you can choose to accept the invalid certificate?

Comment: I use Windows 7 Prof 64 bit, and VS 2010 Premium and have this issue.

Comment: Windows 7 Pro, VS 2010 Pro, can still get this problem, when trying to update NuGet, from NuGet, from version 1.2.20325.9034. to version 2.8.60318.667

Answer (score 192):

1. Close all visual studio 2010 instances.
2. Open visual studio again as administrator
3. Go to "Tools" > "Extension Manager"
4. Uninstall NuGet
5. Install NuGet again.

if you are not able to uninstall it go to:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft Corporation\NuGet Package Manager

and remove this folder.
**deleting this is at your own risk!**

Comment: I sometimes forget that VS needs to run as Admin for some operations.  My uninstall was greyed out, Run as Admin resolved it.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes I had the same problem at first :-)

Comment: first uninstalled from Add remove and then (thanks to juFo) from visual studio extention manger. only then problem solved.

Comment: I wish every fix was this easy =)

Comment: Worked as smoooth as an old cat in a hammered, velvet, smoking jacket, sipping a 27 year old Laphroaig from a Glencairn whiskey glass, with the reassuring sound of a crackling fire in the background.

Comment: 02/28/2013 and I have this issue again, upgrading to version 2.2.40116.9051. Uninstalling and re-installing fixed it.

Comment: Make this the accepted answer. The actual accepted answer is useless.

Comment: @MatthewLock, you are correct. Saying 'This is a known issue' does nothing to help someone resolve the problem. This answer describes precisely the steps one needs to follow to fix this issue.

Comment: It's 2014 and I just had this issue with VS2010 over Windows 8.1 trying to upgrade v2.5 to 2.8. Yes, VS needs to be run as administrator, and yes an update fails but uninstall/re-install work great.

Comment: @MatthewLock is correct.   Stackoverflow is about actually resolving problems, although knowing why the error occurred can be helpful, it's not the main purpose of this site.

Answer (score 3):

From [NuGet page](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c) on VS Gallery website:

*"Review current release notes/known issues on the [NuGet Docs site](http://docs.nuget.org/), including details and solution for about a [common upgrade failure](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2581019) (Visual Studio 2010 SP1 [**Hotfix available**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/hotfix/kbhotfix?kbnum=2581019&kbln=en-us))"*

Comment: This hotfix is not available anymore! Anybody have a working link to download?

Comment: @f470071 I have updated the hotfiх link for you in my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

I uninstalled via Tools | Extension Manager, then was able to install successfully. If I had read [Hanselman's post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetActionPlanUpgradeTo11SetupAutomaticUpdatesGetNuGetPackageExplorer.aspx) a little more carefully, I would have realized 1.0 doesn't play nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you run as admin, and uninstall, and cannot get to the online archive....
you can still install by downloading the vsix file
https://docs.nuget.org/consume/installing-nuget