# NuGet isn't showing any packages

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

[image: Empty NuGet Dialog]
I've tried going to the URL listed for the official package source with my browser and I only get an empty list.  I also tried Phil Haack's source found while Binging this issue and got a similar empty list.

It could be firewall related - I'm at work, now, and this worked just fine the other day when I started playing with NuGet at home.  But NuGet seems to be using my IE settings and I am able to access StackOverflow, as you can see.  :)

Is there a way to download the packages to a local folder?  I would then add that folder to the list of sources for NuGet to check.

Thanks!

Screenshot from work PC of Settings (this one has no packages):
[image]

Screenshot from home PC of Settings (this one sees all packages):
[image]

PCs are currently RIGHT next to each other - both on same wired network connected to same router, etc.!

Comment: What happens when you go to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=206669 in a web browser?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <service xml:base="http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">
- <workspace>
  <atom:title>Default</atom:title> 
- <collection href="Packages">
  <atom:title>Packages</atom:title> 
  </collection>
- <collection href="Screenshots">
  <atom:title>Screenshots</atom:title> 
  </collection>
  </workspace>
  </service>

Comment: You're able to get to the feed then though. If you go to http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/Packages you should see the content.

Comment: Well, my browser can see packages there, sure, but still nothing in NuGet.  Please check out the two screenshots I've added to the question.

Comment: Interesting, Win7/Chrome13 Home PC shows XML for the feed.  WinXP/IE8 Work PC shows a "friendly" page telling me more about how RSS works and listing AdventureWorks, agsXMPP, AjaxControlToolkit, etc.

Comment: OK, not that interesting, sorry.  IE on Win7 also shows the friendly page.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try adding a new package source from that window and set the source to http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc

Comment: When I did that, I was told "There was an error while processing the request.  Please verify that 'http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/Packages' is a valid feed.

Comment: My bad... try it without the "packages" on the end: http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/

Comment: That did it, thanks!  So could it be that WinXP doesn't like the redirect?  Yikes!

Comment: Just FYI, being connected to the Cisco VPN client is also making it not work.  I suspect my company's firewall does not like NuGet for some reason - with or without the redirect.  Without the VPN, it works without the redirect.  Hey, at least I can get there from home - thanks!

Comment: @Steve - Not sure why the redirect was causing problems there, but it's certainly odd. Glad everything's working now.

Answer (score 6):

I was experiencing the same error in VS 2010.  However, the accepted answer by Rick Liddle wasn't working for me.  The strange thing is that I could get a list of available packages from the Package Manager Console no problem, so it still wasn't a connectivity issue.

Finally I realized that a newer version of NuGet was available, so I installed it, and it worked!  Here are the steps:

1. Uninstall NuGet from Windows (Control Panel -> Programs and Features).
2. Uninstall NuGet Package Manager from Visual Studio 2010 (Tools -> Extension Manager).
3. Close Visual Studio.
4. Download and install the latest version of NuGet Package Manager (2.0.30625.9003 at the time of writing) from http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c.

That's it.  As an aside, I noticed that the URI of the NuGet Official Package Source has changed to https://nuget.org/api/v2/ .

Comment: BTW: If updating your NuGet package gives you an error when installing, if you look at the log you could see a SignatureMismatchException. It is a known issue, to fix it take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496640/nuget-upgrade-issue/8655810#8655810).

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue with VS2015. The default package feed (https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/) returned no results. Switched to https://www.nuget.org/api/v2 and was able to find packages again.

Tools->Options->Nuget Package Manager->Package Sources and add new Package Source.

Comment: Awesome this saved me a headache.  If you retain both sources remember to select the Package sources option to "All" in the Visual Studio 2015 nuget browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue today. My list wasn't empty, but it only had 6 pages and nothing I needed was available.

The flag in the top right corner showed there was an updated to the NPM. Updating via that didn't restore the missing packages.

There was an update to Nuget yesterday (2014-04-02).

- Tools > Extensions & Updates > "Nuget Package Manager for Visual Studio 2013" > Uninstall.
- Closed Visual Studio then installed the newest version from

  - VS 2010/2012: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c
  - VS 2013: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ec1526c-4a8c-4a84-b702-b21a8f5293ca
- Started up Visual studio and NPM worked again