# Xamarin in VS - Unable to install Android Support v4

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I installed Visual Studio 2015 to try out Xamarin that comes with the community version, but I have not been able to open a single project. I have downloaded a few projects from GitHub that I want to try out, but they all get the same error. First, it says I am missing a reference/assembly, and I figured this was the Xamarin.Android.Support.v4. So I downloaded this from [Xamarin's website](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamandroidsupportv4-18) and added it to the project. This somewhat worked, however every time I try to build my project, I get an error:

```
NuGet Package restore failed for project AndroidAltBeaconLibrary.Sample: Unable to find version '21.0.3' of package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4'.
```

This error seems to haunt me whatever I try to do. When I open my NuGet manager, I am not able to do anything, as this error pops up here as well (I wanted to try remove the NuGet and add it again). It just says Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 is installed (but not available in this source) regardless of if I remove it from References.

Does anyone have any tips of what to do??

**Edit:** I forgot to mention, the version I downloaded is 23.1.1.1

**Edit 2:** Using the install command does not work in the projects. An error says it needs to restore NuGet packages first, however it is not able to do this either. In a blank project, it is not able to find this NuGet (neither 23.1.1.1 nor 21.0.3.. In fact, when I open NuGet manager, it is not able to find any NuGets at all in the Browse Tab. Is my VS just messed up? Should I reinstall the whole thing??

Comment: Have you tried istalling version 21.0.3? It looks like the project needs that specific version.

Comment: Have you tried updating your Nuget Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the specific 21.0.3 version of `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4`, which Xamarin uses.

[Install it from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4/21.0.3)

Comment: The command console is not able to find this NuGet, see edit.

Comment: Check if Visual Studio can find NuGetPackages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029828/nuget-isnt-showing-any-packages

Comment: Ah, seems my issue was that my package source was empty for some reason. Adding the default nuget.org/api/v2 seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 2):

I have trouble restoring Xamarin.Android.Support nugets too. This solved my issue:

1) allow nuget restore on build (Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings)

2) remove the reference from .csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.23.3.0\lib\MonoAndroid403\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

3) rebuild all (ignore errors, restore will still work)

4) put the reference back to .csproj file

5) rebuild and it should be OK